# How to construct a diffeomorphism with $p_k \mapsto q_k$?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

How to prove the following property? I cannot do anything.

Let $M$ be a connected paracompact smooth manifold of dimension $m\geq 2$. 
Let $(p_k), (q_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ be sequences on $M$ which do not accumulate on anywhere and $i\neq j \Rightarrow p_i\neq p_j, q_i\neq q_j$. 
Let $X_k\in (T_{p_k}M)\backslash\{0\}, Y_k\in (T_{q_k}M)\backslash\{0\}$. 
Then there is a diffeomorphism $\varphi :M\to M$ with
\begin{equation}
\varphi(p_k)=q_k,\ \ \ d\varphi_{p_k}(X_k)=Y_k\ \ \ (k\in\mathbb{N}). 
\end{equation}

Comment: The case of pairs of points (without the condition on the differential) is the topological homogeneity of connected manifolds, for example see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89721/are-all-connected-manifolds-homogeneous . Once you've proven that you're almost done...