# Homeomorphisms of an open set onto itself.

Tags: general-topology

Given two distinct points $a,b\in U$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, can one always find a homeomorphism $f:U\to U$ with $f(a)=b$ or does one need any further conditions on $ U $ or the points?

Thank you.

Comment: What open set $U$ are you talking about? Is $U ⊂ ℝ^n$ where $ℝ^n$ is given euclidean topology?

Comment: Do you want to work with open subsets of $\mathbb R$ or can it be an arbitrary topological spaces? If it is the later, $[0,1]$ as an open subset of the space $[0,1]$ is an easy counterexample.

Comment: Yes I am working with $\mathbb{R}^n$. With Euclidean topology.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @Raisa. It is useful to add such information also to post, where it is easier to spot than in comments. I'll add that I am not sure whether ([tag:fixed-point-theorems]) is really a good tag for this question. You might see some information about what this tag is for in the [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/fixed-point-theorems/info). (And the tag-excerpt was shown to you when adding the tag and you can view it simply by hovering above the tag with your mouse.)

Comment: Do you assume that $U$ is connected? I am not an expert in this area at all, but if $a, b$ are in different connected components of $U$ (e.g. a disk and a punctured disk) then it might be impossible.

Comment: @Martin. No I don't assume connectedness of $U$. But I do want to know if I need to assume it or not. Hence I ask if one needs any further condition on $U$ or the points.

Comment: Related: [Are all connected manifolds homogeneous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89721/are-all-connected-manifolds-homogeneous)

Comment: I think @MartinR's comment basically answers your question. You only need to find two disjoint connected subsets $A$, $B$ which are not homeomorphic. Then $U=A\cup B$ is not homogeneous. (Since any homeomorphism must map connected component to another connected component.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: So if $a, b$ are in the same connected component the answer is "yes", and if $a, b$ lie in different components which are not homeomorphic the answer is "no". I am not sure about the case where $a, b$ lie in different components $A$, $B$ of $U$ which are homeomorphic. From the answer that you linked to I conclude that there is a homeomorphism $f: A \to B$ such that $f(a) = b$. But can this $f$ always be extended to a homeomorphism $f: U \to U$? (Topology was never my main area of expertise, so this may be nonsense.)

Comment: Since [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) are clopen subset which are disjoint and their union is the whole space, any topological space is [topological sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological sum) of the connected components. A map which "exchanges" two homeomorphic summands/components (and leave all other points unchanges) is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @Martin: I see, so simple, thanks! Are you going to post an answer?

Comment: @MartinR If you wish to do so, feel free to summarize (some of the) comments in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seems that all puzzle pieces to answer your question have been found in the 
above discussion. I'll try to summarize it:

> Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $a, b \in U$ be
>   distinct. A homeomorphism $f: U \to U$ with $f(a) = b$ exists
>   if and only if the connected components $A, B$ of $U$ containing $a$
>   and $b$ respectively, are homeomorphic.

In particular, such a homeomorphism exists if $a, b$ lie in the same
connected component of $U$.

The "only if" part is the easier one: If a homeomorphism $f: U \to U$ with $f(a) = b$ exists then $f(A) = B$ because homeomorphisms map connected components 
onto connected components, so $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic.

For the "if" part assume that there is a homeomorphism $g: A \to B$. The crucial tool is
to use the result of

- [Are all connected manifolds homogeneous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89721/are-all-connected-manifolds-homogeneous)

which states that there is a homeomorphism $h: B \to B$ such that $h(g(a)) = b$. 
Then $F := h \circ g : A \to B$ is a homeomorphism from $A$ onto $B$ 
satisfying $F(a) = b$. $F$ can be extended to a homeomorphism $f:U \to U$:
In the case $A \ne B$ define
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= F(x)  &\text{ if } x \in A,  \, \\
f(x) &= F^{-1}(x) &\text{ if } x \in B,  \,\\
f(x) &= x \quad &\text{ if } x \in U \setminus (A \cup B) \, .
\end{align}
$$
$f$ "swaps" the components $A$ and $B$ and leaves all other components unchanged.
And if $A = B$ then define $f$ via
\begin{align}
f(x) &= F(x)  &\text{ if } x \in A,  \, \\
f(x) &= x \quad &\text{ if } x \in U \setminus A \, .
\end{align}