# Existence of a homeomorphism that take one point to another in $\overline{\mathbb{B}}^n$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, normed-spaces

In the proof of the fact the every connected manifolds are topologically homogeneous there is a lemma that I can't tackle to prove.

> Given $p,q\in\mathbb{B}^n$ (the $n$-dimensional unit ball) there is a
> homeomorphism $\varphi$ from $\overline{\mathbb{B}}^n$ to
> $\overline{\mathbb{B}}^n$ such that $\varphi (p) = q$ and
> $\varphi|_{\partial \mathbb{B}^n} = \text{Id}_{\partial \mathbb{B}^n}$.

I know that there is [a straightforward proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/89736) based on vector field but I don't master this tool yet. Also I didn't found any proof about it elsewhere. So is there an elementary proof of that fact ?

Comment: Note: Isn't $f$ its own inverse actually?

Comment: @StefanOctavian Yes that's right. I'll fix it !

Comment: The continuity of your $\varphi$ strongly depends on $\psi$. It won't be continuous for any $\psi$. For example imagine that $\psi$ rotates points. Then clearly boundary can't stay stationary. It is not clear how to pick $\psi$ correctly. The obvious $tan(\lVert v\rVert)\cdot v$ (or any other rescaling) won't work. And so you moved the pile elsewhere, with similar difficulty level.

Comment: @freakish Yes that's the type of morphism I thought to use. But once I set this $\psi$ how can I show that this is continous ? I still don't see how.

Comment: @acd3456 sorry, perhaps you've read my old comment (which was incorrect). The obvious $\psi$ (rescaling) makes your definition **discontinuous**, likely always when both $p,q$ are nonzero. That's because your $\varphi$ is a translation. And so you rescale after translation. So if $t_n\cdot v$ goes to a boundary point $b$, then translated and rescaled $r\cdot( t_n\cdot v + w)$ goes to some other boundary point $b'$.

Comment: @freakish I think $\varphi$ isn't the right morphism to show the topological homogeneity of $\mathbb{B}^n$